# How to get this query in tree view format

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
Sno ECTCodeDescription  ECTHedisCodeTypeCode
1   Outpatient  CPT
2   Outpatient  RevCode
3   Nonacute inpatient  CPT
4   Nonacute inpatient  RevCode
5   ED  CPT
6   ED  RevCode
7   Acute inpatient CPT
8   Acute inpatient RevCode
```

here i am getting result like this and my query is

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Sno = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY ECTCodeDescription DESC
            ),
    EC.ECTCodeDescription,
    CEC.ECTHedisCodeTypeCode
FROM CodeSetHEDIS_ECTCode EC
INNER JOIN CodeSetECTHedisCodeType CEC
    ON EC.ECTHedisCodeTypeID = CEC.ECTHedisCodeTypeID
WHERE ECTHedisTableID = 29 
GROUP BY ECTCodeDescription,
CEC.ECTHedisCodeTypeCode
```

how can i get my output like this one :

```
Sno CODEName            CODEID
1   Outpatient          NULL
2   CPT                 1
3   RevCode             1   
4   Nonacute            NULL    
5   CPT                 4
6   RevCode             4
7   ED                  NULL
8   CPT                 7
9   RevCode             7
10  Acute inpatient     NULL    
11  CPT                 10
12  RevCode             10
```

you can observe Outpatient ID = 1 came for CPT = 1 and Revcode = 1 and Nonacute ID = 4 came for CPT = 4and Revcode = 4

suggest me the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming your table structure and data look something like in [This Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a7fe/1), your new query might look something like this:

```
;WITH CTE_distinct AS 
(
    SELECT ECTCodeDescription FROM CodeSetHEDIS_ECTCode
    GROUP BY ECTCodeDescription
)
, CTE_all AS 
(
    SELECT ECTCodeDescription AS CodeName, 0 AS CodeLevel, ECTCodeDescription AS MainCode  
    FROM CTE_distinct d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ECTHedisCodeTypeCode AS CodeName, 1 AS CodeLevel, c.ECTCodeDescription AS MainCode
    FROM CTE_distinct d
    INNER JOIN dbo.CodeSetHEDIS_ECTCode c ON d.ECTCodeDescription = c.ECTCodeDescription
    INNER JOIN dbo.CodeSetECTHedisCodeType t ON c.ECTHedisCodeTypeID = t.ECTHedisCodeTypeID
)
,CTE_Numbers AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MainCode DESC, CodeLevel) AS Sno
        , *
    FROM CTE_all
)
SELECT sno, CodeName, NULL AS COdeID FROM CTE_Numbers 
WHERE CodeLevel = 0
UNION
SELECT n2.sno, n2.CodeName, n1.sno AS CodeID FROM CTE_Numbers n1
inner JOIN CTE_Numbers n2 ON n1.MainCode = n2.MainCode AND n1.CodeLevel = 0 AND n2.CodeLevel = 1
ORDER BY Sno
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a7fe/2)**

Basically, we separately get those that will have CodeID NULL and those that won't then merge them together for numbering. And at the end separate and merge them again to get correct values in CodeID column.

This last part could also have been done with sub-query instead of union.

```
SELECT sno, CodeName
    , CASE WHEN CodeLevel = 0 THEN  NULL 
           ELSE (SELECT sno FROM CTE_Numbers c2 WHERE c2.MainCode = c1.MainCode AND c2.CodeLevel = 0) 
    END AS CodeID
FROM CTE_Numbers c1
ORDER BY Sno
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a7fe/3)**